# Find Overlapping Region between 3-Dimensional Shapes

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm currently plotting 2 separate 3-dimensional amorphous blobs which overlap each other. I have created the blobs by deforming a unit circle (as you can see in the code provided below). My question is: is there an easy way to isolate the overlapping region? I need to isolate the overlapping region and then color it differently (as in turn the region green, for example) to clearly show where the overlap is. My actual program has many shapes that overlap, however for the sake of simplicity, i have produced the following code to illustrate what i am trying to do:

```
% Create Sphere with 100 points
N = 100;                 % sphere grid points
[X,Y,Z] = sphere(N);     % get x,y,z coordinates for sphere
num=size(X,1)*size(X,2); % get total amount of x-coordinates (m*n)

% Loop through every x-coordinate and apply scaling if applicable
for k=1:num              % loop through every coordinate
   value=X(k);           % store original value of X(k) as value
   if value<0            % compare value to 0
      X(k)=0.3*value;    % if < 0, scale value
   end
end

% Loop through every z-coordinate and apply scaling if applicable
for k=1:num              % loop through every coordinate
   value=Z(k);           % store original value of X(k) as value
   if value>0            % compare value to 0
      Z(k)=0.3*value;    % if < 0, scale value
   end
end

mesh(X,Y,Z,'facecolor','y','edgecolor','y','facealpha',...
    0.2,'edgealpha',0.2); 
hold on
mesh(-1*(X-1),Y,Z,'facecolor','r','edgecolor','r','facealpha',...
    0.2,'edgealpha',0.2); 
hold off
axis equal
```

I'm not necessarliy looking for code, just an effective algorithm or process to achieve the desired results as I need to adapt this result into the more sophisticated program I have.

Answer (score 1):

Maintain an array (n-dimensional) of integers, as you draw your objects, increment each corresponding point in the array. When done, loop through the array, and each element > 1 has an overlap between two or more objects, use the array coordinate to color the objects based on the number of overlaps.

Comment: hmmm, I could see how this would be effective if my shapes had interior points but currently I only have surface points. do you know of an easy way that i could artificially generate interior points?

Comment: @Engineer You will need to create the array by sampling your 3D model, changing it from a surface to a volume.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked in 2D with the MATLAB builtin function `inpolygon` to find out overlapping areas. However, it does not natively support 3d. I would suggest you try the `inhull` function which you can find [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10226-inhull) at file exchange. Please note it only supports convex hulls.

If that doesn´t help you maybe you find some inspiration in [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/122213) discussion.